# find method could not work for date in excel vba

Tags: excel, vba, date, find

I was using .find to search for a particular cell in the range("A20:AD20") containing the same date as variable Lastdate with the following code:

```
Set targetcell = ActiveSheet.Range("A20:AD20").Find(what:=Lastdate, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlPart) //LookAt:=xlWhole does not work either
```

The value of Lastdate when I debugged was 6/1/2013 and the value of cell W20 is also 6/1/2013. I used MsgBox and confirmed that Range("W20").value = Lastdate; however the code above could not find any cell. Could anyone help with it? Thank you a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Try forcing a real date:

```
Sub dural()
    Dim s As String
    s = "8/5/2013"
    Set zell = Cells.Find(What:=CDate(s), After:=Range("A1"), LookIn:=xlFormulas _
                , LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False)
    zell.Select
End Sub
```